# Edit animation UITableViewStyle like addressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I need some help with UITableView. I'm looking for the best solution for creating edit table functionality. I have UITableViewController with data and two modes:

- Edit mode: All fields (like first name, last name, phone, web page etc...)
- View mode: Show only filed rows.

The difficult thing is to animate the rows when a user clicks the edit button.

I want the same animation we have in the address book app on iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution!
[Help from this article](http://adampreble.net/blog/2009/09/editing-a-uitableview-the-animated-insert-row/)

So you need add something like this (thanks Sandy)

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                      [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    if (editing) {

        [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }else {
        [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```

After that 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

will be colled, and you can edit list of cells and their appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in simple.

```
//original position and maybe hidden
someView.frame = CGRect(0,0,0,0);
someView.alpha = 0.0f;
[someView setHidden:YES];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

//what you want it comes out finally, changed position and visible
[someView setHidden:NO];
someView.frame = CGRect(100.0f,100.0f,0,0);
someView.alpha = 1.0f;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I don't have simple UIView.
I have Table and lots of dynamics and different Cells

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

to make the **UItableView** in editing mode.Which give you show and hide the button when you swipe on the row.if your animation is something please let me know.

Comment: is the above ans is helpful?I think you need to reload the table after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

in the case below, I have 2 sections, first section contains a series of settings, first row is a default setting, always there and can't be reordered, and second one contains just one row like 'Add...', editing is only for reordering and deleting so in edit mode I remove the first setting, and remove the 2nd section, and it animates smoothly if you club all your insert/delete within a beginUpdates/endUpdates on the tableview. So for you it would be just the opposite, adding more rows/sections when editing

In Normal mode I have :

```
  Countries           (<-- 1st section)
  - World
  - Argentina
  - USA
                      (<-- 2nd section)
  - Add Countries...
```

In Edit mode I have :

```
  Countries           (<-- 1st section)
  - Argentina    =    (can be removed/reordered)
  - USA          =    (can be removed/reordered)
```

Code looks like:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                      nil];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Club all updates together
    if (editing)
    {
        if( [[CCPollSettings countryCodes] count] < 2) // No country setting
            // Remove complete section
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        else // Remove first default row
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // Remove 'Add...' Section
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // .... Do more stuff after 
    } else {
        if( [[CCPollSettings countryCodes] count] < 2) // No country setting yet
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        else // add back default row
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // Add back 'Add...' Section
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; // Club all updates together
}
```